# Maven - Installing JAR not available in public repositories (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven

When I deploy a successfully build Maven Project, from Eclipse, to Tomcat: the application complains that the jar file is not found.

Steps taken:

**1) Installed JAR in local Maven repository**:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=xmlrpc-1.1.jar -DgroupId=org.apache -DartifactId=xmlrpc -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**2) Edited the POM file in Eclipse with:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**3) Synchronized the Maven dependency to the build path of Eclipse:**

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Any tips on steps to take?

NB: I do not plan to make the jar available in a public repository; as far as I know this particular jar file is not available from a public repository (class file required is: org/apache/xmlrpc/Base64).

Comment: Can you check the WEB-INF/lib folder of your deployed webapp to see if xmlrpc-1.1.jar is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any tips on steps to take?

The steps 1), 2), 3) look corrects. Did you refresh the project under eclipse after that? Do you see the library in the Eclipse classpath? Is the JAR non empty?

Did you check if Maven packages the WAR correctly? If yes (and that would be the expected result) then at least you'll know it's an Eclipse/Tomcat issue.

> NB: I do not plan to make the jar available in a public repository; as far as I know this particular jar file is not available from a public repository (class file required is: org/apache/xmlrpc/Base64).

Old versions of this artifact like [`xmlrpc-1.1.jar`](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/xmlrpc/xmlrpc/1.1/) are available in the repository using the groupId `xmlrpc`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xmlrpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

More recent versions like [`xmlrpc-3.0.x.jar`](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xmlrpc/xmlrpc/) are available using the groupId `org.apache.xmlrpc`.